# Azure iot query returns incorrect "lastActivityTime"

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-node-sdk

I have an azure iot hub with connected devices that made activities.
If I check a specific device twin in azure site, I will get the correct "connectionState" and "lastActivityTime", for example:

```
{
 "deviceId": "test",
 "etag": "AAAAAAAAAAM=",
 "version": 5,
 "status": "enabled",
 "statusUpdateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
 "connectionState": "Connected",
 "lastActivityTime": "2018-02-13T08:35:08.7759733",
},
```

But once I use the query explorer (or registry.query in node sdk) i'm getting wrong connectionState and lastActivityTime, for example, this is the result for the query "SELECT deviceId, lastActivityTime, connectionState FROM devices" in query explorer:

```
{
 "DeviceId": "test",
 "ConnectionState": "Disconnected",
 "LastActivityTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

Why won't the registry query return the correct data?

Thanks,

Comment: This field should be used only for development/debugging purposes. The connection state is updated only for devices using MQTT or AMQP. In fact, when i used the following command to query the twin data,there would be an error as 'ArgumentError: 'device' must have a deviceId property'. Could you please detail you test steps? @J. Doe

Comment: I'm using a device that communicates using MQTT.  I'm not getting that error, did you do the query only on devices?

Comment: I run a device client communicating with the IoT Hub on windows 10 desktop, the connectionState shows Connected, and then use command `iothub-explorer query-twin "SELECT connectionState FROM devices where deviceId='device02'` to query the twin data.

Comment: I tested this in 2 ways, both got the same result. First one was using the azure node-sdk to simulate the device, and the second one is using a device that communicates using MQTT to azure directly. both of them, when pressing the device twin button in azure, shows the correct state, but using the query explorer show incorrect results. You can just use "SELECT * FROM devices", this should also show the wrong state for them.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that at the time when this question was asked the Node.js SDK for Azure IoT Hub did not use the last service API version. This has been fixed with azure-iothub@1.2.5 and iothub-explorer@1.2.1 (published today).

If you run the same query with these new versions, it should work!

Comment: Hi, I update the azure-iothub to 1.2.5 and it's sill won't work.  About the iothub-explorer, i'm using the query explorer in Azure site for additional tests and not that package (and it won't show the correct results there also). The only place that currently shows the real correct state and last activity time is the device twin if you access it directly, and not using a query.

Comment: I have confirmed that by using registry.query, the result is correct. You can also check the result through this command: iothub-explorer query-twin "SELECT * FROM devices where deviceId='<you device id>'".